# TI-BASIC tab character / output formatting

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I've written a program on my TI-nspire CAS calculator that outputs something similar to the following...

```
intercepts

x = 2 and x = 4

y = 0

derivative

2x - 4

turning points

(2, -4)
```

This is obviously a fair bit of information to output over multiple lines in a calculator.
I was wondering how I might go about outputting this a little better, say, placing the x and y intercepts on the same line **seperated by a tab**, or having the turning points **printed on the same line** (if more than one were printed. They're currently kept in a list and iterated through, Disp 'ing each).

Does TI-Basic have a TAB character, or is there a method that allows things to be printed on the same line (through multiple statements. Like Disp but without a trailing newline suffix).

Comment: You seem to know how to concatenate values and strings, why not just use spaces (I'm not sure there is a tab character in TI-BASIC, though my experience is the TI-83+ and the TI-89).

Comment: Because the indentation of the second row would not be consistent (if I were to merge the lines for x and y coordinates), depending on the length of the first.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, tabs have the chance of having the same inconsistent spacing, just in intervals of whatever the tab spacing is instead of space by space. If I recall correct there's some function for determining the length of a string. I would suggest padding your numbers to be a certain length and then just use spaces. (Or if you want to get really fancy, calculate the longest number and use that as the string length to pad the others to instead of a fixed string length).

Answer (score 2):

**There is no TAB character in TI-BASIC.**

I would suggest using spaces and determining the length of the first line if you want the spacing to be consistent.